# Mapbox Android, How to add a button to a Marker

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using the Mapbox Android SDK and I was wondering how you can add a button associated with a Marker pop-up.

*Edit*

[image]

Comment: Hi TIm. can you please help me to visualize your query

Comment: If I create a marker option:

e.g. 
                        mapbox.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(point)
                                .title("Add Placement")
                                .snippet("Some snippet"));

Once a user clicks on that marker, it displays a pop-up window.  I want to be able to add buttons that appear with the pop-up window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own info window adapter, An example doing this can be found in the [demo app here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/annotations/CustomInfoWindowActivity.java). Important code to use:

```
mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
      @Nullable
      @Override
      public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {

      ...

      // return the view which includes the button

      }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!  @cammace, do you know why the initial offset is off? When I move the mapview it automatically centers, but initially it's not centered.

Comment: Could you contact me through our [contact page](https://www.mapbox.com/contact/) or on Github with a video or gif? This sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/BMIjEPUUDtZNC/giphy.gif I have submitted to your contact page a link to this gif.  As you can see, it'll initially be offset to the right by a little, but the second I move the mapview it centers properly.

Comment: Can you also post your adapter code and info window layout. Sounds like you are letting the layout match parent which is causing the issue. Once you scroll the map it is correct since the mapview is invalidated. If you define measurements for all the views, it should resolve the issue. For example, removing the image size defined in [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/annotations/CustomInfoWindowActivity.java#L86) will result in the same behavior exhibited in the GIF above.

Comment: @cammace but the custom window is not centered on marker.